# How can I upgrade a Symfony2 app that is hosting my site?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.0

I maked site on 2.0.7, today's actual version is 2.0.9. And I'm quite new to Symfony2.
How I can upgrade my Symfony app without any problems?

Comment: I don't using Git, just copy it from Symfony's web-site

Comment: I've get version with vendord, but is no doubt to getting version w/o vendors.

Comment: What if appKernel is upgraded in new version, but mine appKernel inclide my bundles and some other bundles

Comment: if you upgrade the deps its not going to touch the `appKernel.php` its only going to update the bundles (even the core framework is just a group of bundles).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the deps and deps.lock files linked in the announcement on the symfony blog and run

```
php bin/vendors install
```

That will do the trick

Comment: > Installing/Updating symfony
 M check_cs
 M vendors.php
"symfony" has local modifications. Please revert or commit/push them before running this command again. --- Which files is this? There is no file named check_cs and no vendors.php